# MS SQL Database Table Prefix from Previous Owner

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schema, owner

I have an MS SQL 2000 database that was backed up from a public server and restored at a test location for an upgrade test. The problem is that the user that had access permission on the public server does not exist on the testing server, and now all tables are prefixed with that username (which requires ALL queries against those tables to be changed!)

Is there any quick way to fix this? I have changed the database owner but this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer - the OBJECT owner must be changed to DBO, negating the need to prefix references to your object in your SQL scripts/queries - the object in this case being the database table(s)

Here is a script that will change the owner for objects within a database (not my own code)

```
DECLARE @currentObject nvarchar(517)
DECLARE @qualifiedObject nvarchar(517)
DECLARE @currentOwner varchar(50)
DECLARE @newOwner varchar(50)

SET @currentOwner = 'old_owner'
SET @newOwner = 'dbo'

DECLARE alterOwnerCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [name] FROM dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE xtype = 'U' or xtype = 'P'
AND LEFT([name], 2) <> 'dt'
OPEN alterOwnerCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM alterOwnerCursor INTO @currentObject
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @qualifiedObject = CAST(@currentOwner as varchar) + '.' + CAST(@currentObject as varchar)
   EXEC sp_changeobjectowner @qualifiedObject, @newOwner
   FETCH NEXT FROM alterOwnerCursor INTO @currentObject
END
CLOSE alterOwnerCursor
DEALLOCATE alterOwnerCursor
```

Comment: Did you read the question: this still means changing all queries that have the schema reference

Comment: "Read the question"? He asked it!

Comment: @gbn: this is a script that changes the OWNER of the table objects which means that they can once again be referenced without a prefix

e.g. Originally, the tables were called tblWhatever. 
Then when moved to test server, they became called olduser.tblWhatever. 
The script changes the owner to DBO making them now called dbo.tblWhatever. 
Any table with the prefix "dbo" can be referenced without specifying that "dbo" prefix i.e. tblWhatever OR dbo.tblWhatever, meaning you dont need to change any queries :)

Answer (score 1):

Create the login and users, but find out the SID from sysusers

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'TheLogin', 'ThePassword', @sid = ???
EXEC sp_adduser 'TheLogin','TheUser'
```

Note: SQL Server 2000 so can't use CREATE LOGIN or CREATE USER